# Subdividing the Not an Answer queue

Tags: feature-request, review, answers

As we know there is a problem with the queue to verify “Not an Answer” rejections.

I try to comment on every answer that I flag, and a couple of cases come up repeatedly and seem to warrant either a subdivision of the category or their own flag.

Most often, my comment begins, *"Stack Overflow isn't a blog"*, and I continue with one of

- If you need help, then please ask your own question
- This doesn't solve the question, and belongs as a comment

To stem the tide of unresolved “Not an Answer” judgements, I suggest that we have

- Not an Answer: Should Be a Comment
- Not an Answer: Should Be a New Question

The exceptions would fall under the current “Not an Answer” category, and could then receive appropriate attention instead of being swept through the fast lane as now.